# C++ vs. Fortran parallel MM speed difference loop tiling

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran, matrix-multiplication

I can't figure out why this implementation of matrix multiplication runs 3 times slower in C++ then the respective Fortran code when run in parallel. It's approx. the same for the serial version.

```
program scheduling
!$  use omp_lib
implicit none

integer :: i,j,k,y,x,z
integer, parameter :: tile = 8, N = 1000
double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: a,b,c,d ! data must be allocated on the heap, otherwise OpenMP would allocate it in the stack and an stackoverflow would  occur for larger matrices.
double precision :: E,S

allocate(a(N*N))
allocate(b(N*N))
allocate(c(N*N))
allocate(d(N*N))

call random_seed()
call random_number(b)
call random_number(a)

!transpose b
do i = 1,N 
   do j = 1,N
      d((i-1)*N+j) = b((j-1)*N+i)
   end do
end do

S = omp_get_wtime()

!$OMP PARALLEL DO SHARED(a,d,c) PRIVATE(i,j,k,x,y,z) SCHEDULE(static) 
do i = 1,N,tile
   do j = 1,N,tile
      do k = 1,N,tile
         do x = i, min( i+tile-1,N)
            do y = j, min( j+tile-1,N)
               do z = k, min( k+tile-1,N)
                  c((x-1)*N+y) = c((x-1)*N+y) + a((x-1)*N+z) * d(z+(y-1)*N)
               enddo
            enddo
          enddo
       enddo
    enddo
 enddo
 !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
 E = omp_get_wtime()  
 print*, (E-S)

 ! Deallocation of memory
 deallocate(a)
 deallocate(b)
 deallocate(c)
 deallocate(d)

end program scheduling
```

and compile with:

```
$ gfortran -O3 -fopenmp scheduling.f08 -o scheduling
$ ./scheduling
0.901.... !for the parallel version and
1.3496... !for the serial version
```

(which is btw. slower than the index version such as a(i,j))

and the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i,j,k,x,y,z;
    const int N = 1000;
    double* a = new double[N*N];
    double* b = new double[N*N];
    double* c = new double[N*N];
    double* d = new double[N*N];

    int tile = 8; 

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            a[i*N+j] = rand()%1000; 
            b[i*N+j] = rand()%1000; 
        }
    }
    // transpose
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            d[i*N+j] = b[i+j*N];
        }   
    }
    double start = omp_get_wtime();

//#pragma omp parallel for shared(a,c,d) private(i,j,k,x,y,z) schedule(static)
    for( i = 0; i < N; i+=tile){
        for( j = 0; j < N; j+=tile){
            for( k = 0; k < N; k+=tile){
                for( x = i; x < std::min(i+tile,N); x++){
                    for( y = j; y < std::min(j+tile,N); y++){
                        for( z = k; z < std::min(k+tile,N); z++){
                            c[x*N+y] = c[x*N+y] +  a[x*N+z] * d[z+y*N];
                        }   
                    }     
                }
            }   
        }   
    } 

    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    std::cout << (end-start) << std::endl;

    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;
    delete[] d;

    return 0;

}

$g++ -O3 -fopenmp parallel.cpp -o parallel
$./parallel
2.347... //for the parallel version and 
1.47...  //for the serial one
```

I really don't see the difference between the two codes. It should be approx. the same but it's not. And I have no idea why. From the serial version it's seems that the code is right (or at least what I expected) however the parallel one runs very differently.

Comment: My guess is that the Fortran compiler was able to vectorize the code in presence of OpenMP directives, but the C++ compiler was not. And that's easy to check: try running the OpenMP version with a single thread (via OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable), and compare to the performance of the serial version compiled without OpenMP.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Good point. So with one thread it takes 4.953 sec. Any ideas on which directives to use?

Comment: what's your version of GCC?

Comment: I played with your C++ code on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 4.8.2. The problem is reproducible, the code becomes slower with `#pragma omp parallel for`. I used `-fopt-info-vec-optimized` and `-fopt-info-vec-missed` to get vectorization report; if these options work correctly, loops were not vectorized for either version. So, some optimization is obviously missed but it's unclear which one.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've been a great help. At least now I have somewhere to start the search. Although, interestingly enough I get a similar error without omp.

Comment: Just for the sake of discussion I should add that I just ran the loop without the tiling, so just i++,j++,k++ etc. There is no vectorization either, but using omp parallel for makes the MM twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to explicitly specify the number the threads. Here is what I changed:

```
... ceteris paribus ...
#pragma omp **omp_set_num_threads(2)** parallel for shared(a,c,d) private(i,j,k,x,y,z) 
... 

$ ./MM
0.98...
```

which is a bit faster then the serial version. But at least not a lot slower.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why you believe it is necessary? Do you have `OMP_NUM_THREADS` set in your shell?

Comment: I tried it out and it was faster. No, i did not have it in the shell. In fact, I have no idea why, I can only guess.